# Alert is not a function inside IIFE

Tags: javascript

As soon as execution context goes inside IIFE, it says alert is not a function. Is there any specific thing that i need to know about IIFE. or Am i doing something wrong ?

```js
var test = 0;

function makeTest() {
  var test = 10;
  alert(test);
  alert(window.test)
    (function() {
      var test = 20;
      alert(test);
      alert(window.test);
    })();
}
alert(test);
makeTest();
alert(test);
```

Comment: You forgot a semicolon

Comment: not answer, but IIFE usually cause confusion, use `let` and block `{.....}` reduce these noise.

Comment: @CertainPerformance. perfect... Whoooo !! Thank a bunch... !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says `alert(...)` is not a function, not `alert` is not a function.

Your code is attempting to do this:

```
alert(window.test)(function () { })();
```

… as you are falling victim to automatic semi-colon insertion not working the way you expect.

i.e. You are **calling** the *return value* of `alert()` and passing your anonymous function as an argument.

Be explicit about where statements end. Use semi-colons.

```js
var test = 0;

function makeTest() {
  var test = 10;
  alert(test);
  alert(window.test);
  (function() {
    var test = 20;
    alert(test);
    alert(window.test);
  })();
}
alert(test);
makeTest();
alert(test);
```

Or use `let` in a block instead of an IIFE:

```js
var test = 0;

function makeTest() {
  let test = 10;
  alert(test);
  alert(window.test)
  {
    let test = 20;
    alert(test);
    alert(window.test);
  }
}
alert(test);
makeTest();
alert(test);
```

Comment: @appleapple — The fixed indentation was caused by me hitting Tidy when I converted the OP's code into a runnable demo.

Comment: oh really, then OP may also needs to use a better editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a semicolon after `alert(window.test)` so your code will look like:

```
var test = 0; 
function makeTest() {
    var test = 10;
    alert(test);
    alert(window.test);
    (function() {
        var test = 20; 
        alert(test);
        alert(window.test);
    })();
}
alert(test);
makeTest();
alert(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh what a difference a semicolon (or lack thereof) can make.

```
alert(window.test)
(function() {
  var test = 20;
  alert(test);
  alert(window.test);
})();
```

Note the missing semicolon after the first alert. Its absence means you are effectively doing jQuery-style **chaining** of methods - i.e. your code is treating the IIEF as a method of what is returned by the alert. This is easier to visualise in a truncated example:

```
alert('foo')(function() { /* ... */ })();
```

Since 'foo' clearly has no method constituting an IIEF, this errors.

Comment: "*Query-style chaining of methods*"??? A jQuery style chaining **of methods** would be `$().find().parent().style()` for example. I can't remember anywhere in jQuery where you'd have **functions** returning **functions** so you'd have to do `a()()`